# optimising multiple if statements in pyspark

Tags: if-statement, pyspark

I am trying to convert if statements written in sas to pyspark;
Below is the code:
Query here is they directly mention column name and perform if function.
However if we use pyspark, we would use it df[colname].
There are lot of if statements; is their any way to cover this in a single syntax/statement.

```
if S1= "" and S2= "" then
        do
        S1= S0- S3;
            S2= 0;
        end;

    if CS1= "" and CS2= "" then
        do
        CS1= CS0 - CS3;
            CS2= 0;
        end;

    if S1< 0 then
        S1= 0;
    if S2< 0 then
        S2= 0;
    if CS1< 0 then
        CS1= 0;
    if CS2< 0 then
        CS2= 0;
    if IMP1= "" then
        IMP1= 0;
    if IMP2= "" then
        IMP2= 0;
    if CIMP1 = "" then
        CIMP1 = 0;
    if CIMP2 = "" then
        CIMP2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question quite right. From what I understand, we can do the same thing in pyspark also ("they directly mention column name and perform if function"). Here's your sample code converted. It is generated by an automated tool called SPROCKET and millions of such 'if' conditions can be converted under a minute with it.

```
.withColumn('S1', expr("""case
    when (S1= '' and S2= '') then S0- S3
    else S1 end"""))
.withColumn('S2', expr("""case
    when (S1= '' and S2= '') then 0
    else S2 end"""))

.withColumn('CS1', expr("""case
    when (CS1= '' and CS2= '') then CS0 - CS3
    else CS1 end"""))
.withColumn('CS2', expr("""case
    when (CS1= '' and CS2= '') then 0
    else CS2 end"""))

.withColumn('S1', expr("""case
    when (S1< 0) then 0
    else S1 end"""))
.withColumn('S2', expr("""case
    when (S2< 0) then 0
    else S2 end"""))
.withColumn('CS1', expr("""case
    when (CS1< 0) then 0
    else CS1 end"""))
.withColumn('CS2', expr("""case
    when (CS2< 0) then 0
    else CS2 end"""))
.withColumn('IMP1', expr("""case
    when (IMP1= '') then 0
    else IMP1 end"""))
.withColumn('IMP2', expr("""case
    when (IMP2= '') then 0
    else IMP2 end"""))
.withColumn('CIMP1', expr("""case
    when (CIMP1 = '') then 0
    else CIMP1 end"""))
.withColumn('CIMP2', expr("""case
    when (CIMP2 = '') then 0
    else CIMP2 end"""))
```